# [KBase: defaultKieBase]: Error importing : 'org.jbpm.demo.itorders.Order'

Tags: jboss, jbpm, kie

I am following [doc1](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.25.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/index.html#_import_your_business_assets_project_into_business_central) & [doc2](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.25.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/index.html#_launch_business_application_in_development_mode)

In order to execute the Sample that you provided ITOrders in development mode.

1. I clone from this [Git](https://github.com/business-applications/sample-itorders-application)
2. Import itorders-application-kjar into business-central ( jbpm server )

However, when I tried to build the Kjar project, I got those errors:

> 1. [KBase: defaultKieBase]: Error importing : 'org.jbpm.demo.itorders.Order'
> 2. [KBase: defaultKieBase]: Rule Compilation error Only a type can be imported. org.jbpm.demo.itorders.Order resolves to a package
> 3. [KBase: defaultKieBase]: Rule Compilation error Only a type can be imported. org.jbpm.demo.itorders.Order resolves to a package Order cannot be resolved to a type Order cannot be resolved to a type
> 4. [KBase: defaultKieBase]: Rule Compilation error Only a type can be imported. org.jbpm.demo.itorders.Order resolves to a package Order cannot be resolved to a type Order cannot be resolved to a type

and It ends up.

> 5. Build of module 'itorders-application-kjar' (requested by wbadmin) completed. Build: FAILURE

Could you indicate me how I will be able to import itorders-application-model into jbpm server and binding it to the kjar project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dependency of the business-application-model project to business-application-service and business-application-kjar project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>business-application-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The dependency to the kjar project can be added via the business central going to settings of the project. Then you can get your changes back into your codebase and fire a launch clean install.